# How to GET and Persist Action<S,E> from StateMachine?

Tags: spring-boot, state-machine, saga, spring-statemachine

I have a Spring StateMachine, everything runs smoothly and I am persisting some part of stateMachine Manually (I think Spring StateMachine does not it behind the hood):

```
var sources = new JpaRepositoryState(stateMachine.getId(), transition.getSource().getId().name(), Boolean.FALSE);

        var targets = new JpaRepositoryState(stateMachine.getId(), transition.getTarget().getId().name(), Boolean.FALSE);



        var toPersist = new JpaRepositoryTransition(stateMachine.getId(), sources, targets, message.getPayload().name());
        jpaStateRepository.save(targets);
        jpaStateRepository.save(sources);

        transitionRepository.save(toPersist);
```

Now I really want to persist the Actions occured during a State Transition. Have someone managed to do? An example would be appreciated.